# Remainder of dividing $x^{137}+x+1$ by $x+5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

In $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]$, what is the remainder of dividing $x^{137}+x+1$ by $x+5$?

I can not find how to solve this problem of modular arithmetic. Anybody could tell me only as I proceed to solve this exercise?

Comment: Do you think you can simplify $x + 5$ in $\mathbf{Z}_5[x]$?

Comment: no. It is a mistake. is In $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]$,

Comment: Do you know about quotient rings?

Comment: little bit. I'm trying to solve a problem that said, what is the remainder of dividing x ^ 137 + x + 1 in x + 5? in $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]$

Comment: Yes, I understand. The reason I was asking is because quotient rings provide a way to understand why the remainder theorem works. Matt Rigby's answer below is correct.

Answer (score 5):

The remainder theorem still works, so it's equal to $(-5)^{137} + (-5) + 1 \mod 7$.

Answer (score 0):

Fermat's Little Theorem says that, modulo $7$,  $x^7 \equiv x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.  That provides you a simple method for reducing powers:
$x^{137} \equiv x^{131} \equiv x^{125} \equiv \cdots x^{5}$.  That reduces it to a simpler problem.  Combine this with Matt Rigby's solution and the problem should be pretty easy to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Over any ring, the polynomial $x-a$ divides $x^n-a^n$ for all natural numbers $n$.Then, for our case, we will have
$$x+5\ \mid\ \left(x^{137}-(-5)^{137}\ +\ x-(-5)\ +\ 1-1\right) $$
Using the congruence notation, this is
$$x^{137} + x + 1 \equiv (-5)^{137}+(-5)+1 \pmod{x+5}\,.$$
Note that we indeed expect a *constant* polynomial as the remainder, since it must have strictly less degree than the divisor.

Observe also that $-5$ can be replaced to $2$ as we work over $\Bbb Z_7$.